# Heavy tail parameter estimation with R

Tags: r

I need to estimate the alpha parameter of the tail of a Pareto-like distribution. I am triyng to do it with R. After a little googling i have found this [reference](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/aws/html/awstindex.html). I tried to install directly the asw library with the function `install.packages('aws')`. R answered me

```
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
package ‘aws’ is not available
```

So i have tried with the sos library

```
findFn('awstindex')
found 0 matches
x has zero rows;  nothing to display.
Warning message:
In findFn("awstindex") : HIT not found in HTML;  processing one page only.
```

Why R can't find this library? Are there different functions to measure the tail parameter with R?

Comment: `install.packages("aws", repos="http://cran.at.r-project.org")` works for me.

Comment: thanx, perfect. But why not all repositories have this library?

Comment: Wait a moment the function `awstindex()` seems doesn't exist. `

Comment: @emanuele, you might be able to find a solution [in the laeken package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/laeken/laeken.pdf), though I'm not really sure about the reference. You could take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you open to other implementations? Here is the use of a function mentioned by the fitdistrplus packages documentation as having particular use in estimating Pareto parameters.

```
require(fitdistrplus)
require(actuar)  # to get a random Pareto function
rpar1000 <- rpareto(1000, 2.5, 3)
mgedist(rpar1000,"pareto",gof="ADR", start=list(shape=1, scale=1))
#------ the ADR measure weights the right tail observations ----------
$estimate
   shape    scale 
2.356235 2.871350 

$convergence
[1] 0

$value
[1] 0.2150991

$hessian
          shape     scale
shape  90.15040 -55.60725
scale -55.60725  35.04152

$gof
[1] "ADR"

$optim.function
[1] "optim"

$loglik
[1] -1612.233
```